# ncmpcpp timeout; mpd not working

Tags: mpd, ncmpcpp

Ncmpcpp was working just fine before I ran an update and now it gives me a "Timeout while connecting" error, so I cannot use it. I try running mpd and I get this error:

```
socket: Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use
```

This is my mpd config file:

```
music_directory     "~/Music"
playlist_directory      "~/Playlists"
db_file         "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.db"
log_file            "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file            "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file          "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.state"
sticker_file            "~/.local/share/mpd/sticker.sql"

bind_to_address     "localhost"
log_level           "default"
port                "6600"
restore_paused "yes"
metadata_to_use "artist,album,title,track,name,genre,date"
auto_update "yes"

input {
    plugin "curl"
}

audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "pulse audio"
}

audio_output {
    type        "fifo"
    name        "mpd_fifo"
    path        "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
    format      "44100:16:2"
    host        "localhost"
}
```

This is the important part of my ncmpcpp config file:

```
ncmpcpp_directory = ~/.config/ncmpcpp
lyrics_directory = ~/.lyrics
mpd_music_dir = ~/Music/library
mpd_host = localhost
mpd_port = 6600
mpd_connection_timeout = 5
```

Can someone help me at all? Any guidance at all?

Comment: The error message "`socket: Failed to bind to '127.0.0.1:6600': Address already in use.`" says you have left a previous `mpd` process running. Try again after `pkill -9 mpd`

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I tried pkill before, but not with "-9"